# Async thunk breaks react app in useEffect

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

I’ve been working on a react crud application to teach myself redux toolkit, and I can’t seem to get a particular async function to work. I’m trying to fetch recipes from a certain user from firebase - this function worked when I was just playing around and didn’t have any users or authentication (i.e., the database was just recipes), but now that I have authentication and users, I cannot fetch or display the recipes, and the recipes are not added to the recipes state array. Thanks to redux logger, I can see that the recipes are accessed from firebase, but they're not displayed or added to the recipes state. Once I refresh the page, the application breaks. I can add and delete recipes to a user in firebase, though.

Here’s what the async thunk looks like:

```
   'user/getRecipes',
   async(uid, thunkAPI) => {
       const snapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, `users/${uid}/recipes`))
       const array = []
       snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
           array.push(doc.data())
       })
       return array 
   }
)
```

Here’s where I call it inside a useEffect. I’ve tried using the uid as an argument and getting the uid with getState() inside the thunk - it doesn’t seem to make a difference but maybe I’m doing that wrong, as well?

```
const RecipeApp = () => {
 
   const dispatch = useDispatch()
   const recipes = useSelector((state) => state.recipes)
   const auth = getAuth()
   const navigate = useNavigate()
   const [user, loading, error] = useAuthState(auth)
   const uid = useSelector(state => state.users.uid.user)
 
   useEffect(() => {
       if (loading) return;
       if (!user) return navigate("/");
   }, [user, loading])
 
   useEffect(() => {
       dispatch(getRecipes(uid))
       console.log(uid)
   }, [dispatch])
 
   const addRecipe = (name, ingredients, instructions, notes) => {
       const date = new Date()
       const newRecipe = {
           name: name,
           ingredients: ingredients,
           instructions: instructions,
           notes: notes,
           recipeId: uuidv4(),
           date: date.toLocaleDateString(),
           createdAt: Date.now(),
          
       }
       dispatch(addRecipeToFirestoreAndRedux(newRecipe)) 
   }
 
   return (
       <div className="recipeapp">
 
           <h1 className='recipeapp__heading'>Recipes</h1><button onClick={logout}>Log out</button>
           <div className="recipeapp__container">
               <ErrorBoundary
                   FallbackComponent={ErrorFallBack}>
                   <RecipeList
                       recipes={recipes}
                      
 
                   />
 
               </ErrorBoundary>
 
               <AddRecipe
                   addRecipe={addRecipe}
               />
           </div>
 
       </div>
   );
}
 
export default RecipeApp;
```

Here’s what the relevant code (and a little more) of the recipes reducer looks like:

```
export const recipeSlice = createSlice({
   name: 'recipesSlice',
   initialState: {
       recipes: []
 
   },
   reducers: {
       ADD_RECIPE: (state, action) => {
           state.recipes.push(action.payload)
       },
       DELETE_RECIPE: (state, action) => {
           state.recipes = state.recipes.filter((recipe) => recipe.recipeId !== action.payload.recipeId)
       },
   extraReducers: builder => {
       builder.addCase(getRecipes.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
           state.recipes = action.payload
       })
   }
 
})
 
export const { ADD_RECIPE, DELETE_RECIPE } = recipeSlice.actions;
 
export default recipeSlice.reducer
```

And here's what the store.js file looks like:

```
import { configureStore, combineReducers } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import recipeReducer from './features/recipeslice'
import userReducer from './features/authentication'
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import logger from "redux-logger";

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    recipes: recipeReducer,
    users: userReducer
})


export const store = configureStore({
    reducer: rootReducer,
    middleware: [thunk, logger]
})
```

Apologies if this is overkill. Hopefully this makes sense, and thank you in advance for any and all help!

Comment: Any errors in the console when it breaks or after refresh?

Comment: After refresh, which is also when it breaks. But even when it isn't throwing an error, I'm still not able to see the data from from firebase in the "recipes" state object, if that makes sense

Comment: What does `getDocs` look like?

Comment: The `uid` is missing from the useEffect dependency array.

Comment: @MuhammadNoumanRafique unfortunately, adding uid to the dependency array did not work.

Comment: @markerikson getDocs returns a promise that, when looped over, returns an array of objects from firestore (which is what I expect).